# How do I force `gpg2` to always produce the same output for the same input?

Tags: gpg

When the same string is encrypted with `gpg2` multiple times, the result would differ, even when the encryption key is the same.

```
$ echo "secret message" | gpg2 --batch --passphrase-file /tmp/key --output - --symmetric > /tmp/r
$ xxd r
00000000: 8c0d 0409 0302 49c1 3718 910a c1ca f3d2  ......I.7.......
00000010: 4401 85a4 6885 26ef 7d4f c403 984d 6c03  D...h.&.}O...Ml.
00000020: 8c68 9ba9 4ea6 b214 2e9c 474a 0666 be52  .h..N.....GJ.f.R
00000030: 5d79 53cd d24b 387f 56e1 3a22 4401 a407  ]yS..K8.V.:"D...
00000040: 881b c641 8b10 b1e7 6662 aaee 3382 7151  ...A....fb..3.qQ
00000050: 565b 172e 74                             V[..t
$ echo "secret message" | gpg2 --batch --passphrase-file /tmp/key --output - --symmetric > /tmp/r
$ xxd r
00000000: 8c0d 0409 0302 dde5 397c 8bfa 4c29 f3d2  ........9|..L)..
00000010: 4401 ca3d bba8 8259 b9e9 7a18 4031 9e86  D..=...Y..z.@1..
00000020: 4861 ddca 8bf3 dbff f4c7 c40e be3f 4092  Ha...........?@.
00000030: 5dec 4dab ef31 3712 1fa3 76e1 4381 ed6f  ].M..17...v.C..o
00000040: bb0d ca49 be0d 4256 9049 2468 07da 3ba7  ...I..BV.I$h..;.
00000050: c338 74e8 d4                             .8t..
```

This is happening because every time `gpg2` runs, [it uses two random blocks](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/89249/7684) at the beginning of the stream.

How do I force `gpg2` to always produce the same output for the same input?

---

Some may wonder, why do I need such a thing. In fact, I'm using `gpg2` to encrypt the files before sending them off-site for a backup.

I want to be able to resume a backup of a large file if it is interrupted (for whatever reason: an issue with the network, a remote server crash, etc.) With deterministic encryption, this is easy: get the number of uploaded bytes (of encrypted content), encrypt the file again, check the hash of the *N* bytes, and if they match, continue with the remaining ones. If the encryption result is not deterministic, however, it is impossible to resume the uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The most commonly accepted definitions of security (e.g., semantic security and adaptive chosen-ciphertext security) do not admit deterministic encryption.

To see why, imagine that I ask you two yes/no questions, and that you encrypt the answers to me deterministically under some pre-shared key.  With deterministic encryption, any eavesdropper would learn whether or not your answer to the two questions is the same.

There are of course some less secure forms of encryption targeted at niche use cases (e.g., convergent encryption).  But a general-purpose encryption tool such as gpg needs to provide better security, since it is intended for general use.

**Update** If you want a reference, you can look at the GPG source code in `agent/protect.c`.  You will see that the IV is getting set from `gcry_create_nonce`, which you can find documented in [the libgcrypt manual](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Retrieving-random-numbers.html#Retrieving-random-numbers) as:

> Fill *buffer* with *length* unpredictable bytes. This is commonly called a nonce and may also be used for initialization vectors and padding. This is an extra function nearly independent of the other random function for 3 reasons: It better protects the regular random generator’s internal state, provides better performance and does not drain the precious entropy pool.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any references that prove that this cannot be done? In terms of security, I understand that it makes sense to make the output non-deterministic *by default*, but it would also make sense to add an option which would let the caller specify the first two blocks, in order to make it deterministic.